# How To detect browser closing through asp.net web services

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, websocket, webservice-client

I have a application where I am doing recording through a third party device.Recording is started and stopped through a asp.net web service which uses the api of the recording device to start and stop the recording..

I am able to start and stop the recording through ajax in normal cases and the functiaanilty works fine in all browsers..

But,once accidently one user without stopping the video,closed the browser in which case the recording could not be stopped..and it went on recording...

So,please suggest me a way so that I can detect the time or anything that tells me when the browser is closed and then I can pass the off request to stop the recording..!!

I have read about `WEB SOCKETS` but they say this class is to be used in VS2012..So,I have not found any compatible solutions yet..